# How to upload one file repository to Gist, preserving history?

Tags: git, github, gist

I have a Git repository on my computer with a single file `coins.py`

How can I get that as  a Gist on Github, preserving history?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is actually quite simple. You can move your existing history into a Gist repo like you would move it into any other:

1. Create a Gist (simply enter a few random characters, so it gets created; enter a title if you want)
2. Copy the URL of the newly created Gist (it has the form `https://gist.github.com/<LONG-HEXNUMBER>.git` (if you prefer using SSH URLs, you can use `git@gist.github.com:<THAT-SAME-HEXNUMBER>.git` instead)
3. In your existing local repo, do `git remote add origin <URL>`, where `origin` is an unused local name for the remote
4. Push your changes: Assuming you have a local `master` branch, you will want to overwrite the remote one with `git push -f origin master`
5. Push any other branches or tags you want on the remote as usual.