# Upload public repo to a private gist

Tags: git, github, gist

I have a local git repo in my machine with multiple files. I created a private gist. How can I upload my local repo to the private gist so that it also preserves the history?

Answer (score -1):

You can't (or maybe you can, but it's at the least very tricky; see the comments below).  [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) is a GitHub-provided *file* service,<sup>1</sup> but a *repository* is not a file.  GitHub provide *repository* hosting as well, and you can upload a repository—a collection of commits, plus names (branch and tag names mainly) that help you find those commits—to a GitHub-provided repository.  Hence you can just use a [regular (but private) GitHub repository](https://github.com/new) to get what you want.

---

<sup>1</sup>Apparently, the file service has a Git repository "underneath" it, and you can access the *public* ones: see [How to upload one file repository to Gist, preserving history?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16500163/1256452)

Comment: FYI: a gist is a repository. You can use **git clone** on a gist. Then you have the typical structure including a **.git** directory.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Interesting. Can you `git push` *to* this repository?

Comment: I do not know. I just tried and received a 403 error **remote: Permission to write to gist denied.**. However, a quick Google search shows others doing that. The **gh gist** command shows clone, create, delete, etc but not push.

Comment: @torek [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500163/how-to-upload-one-file-repository-to-gist-preserving-history) shows how you can upload to a public gist...but not sure how would you upload to a private gist.